# Use an acronym for a bibliographic entry with no author

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I want to cite a work that does not have a specific author, using BibLaTeX and APA.

I want it to appear in the reference list [like this](https://apastyle.apa.org/learn/faqs/cite-book-no-author), but with the acronym -- say, `MW` -- followed by an equal sign in the front (and without the location as that is no longer required):

> MW = *Merriam-Webster's collegiate dictionary* (11th ed.). (2005). Merriam-Webster.

The prescribed reference format (without the acronym and the equal sign) can be produced with the following code:

```
@book{mw,
    title = {Merriam-{W}ebster's collegiate dictionary},
    edition = {11},
    publisher = {Merriam-Webster},
    date = {2005},
}
```

I have tried `shorttitle` but it affects the in-text citations and doesn't appear in the reference list.

How can I add the acronym in front of the entry in the reference list?

Comment: For what it's worth, the book in question is generally labelled "MW11", not "MW". Hence, I'd use `MW11` as the acronym.

Comment: Thanks, but it is just an example and not the work I want to cite.

Comment: I will readily admit that my mind-reading skills are utterly worthless. :-(

Comment: `shorthand = {mw}` or `label = {mw}`. The former trumps; the latter is a fallback. Since you provide no usable code, this is obviously untested.

Comment: They change the in-text citation, not the bibliographic entry in the reference list.

Comment: You would have to patch/change the driver for the "book" type in the style you are using. Normally this would be in the "SHORTAUTHOR" field which the biblatex APA style already uses to do acronyms in citations (see APA style documentation, page 6, Table 1)